# Display mark instead of line in tikz legend

Tags: legend

When using

```
    \addplot[color=black, mark=o, draw=none] table [y=Y, x=X]{Data/bottoms.dat};
    \addlegendimage{New record};
    \addplot[color=black, mark=x, draw=none] table [y=Y, x=X]{Data/breaks.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Discarded solution};
    \addplot[color=black, mark=*, draw=none] table [y=Y, x=X]{Data/restarts.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Reset to record}
```

the displayed labels next to "New record", "Discarded solution" and "Reset to record" are just plain black lines, but I would like them to be "o", "x" and "*", respectively. How can I get the marks instead of the lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this. Since no codes and datun were supplied. This solution made 3 simple data files and incorporate them into the code via `filecontents`. Add these

```
\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=o}
\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=x}
\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=*}
```

Use of `legend cell align=center` for other text/label alignments.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
X Y
1  3
2  4
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data2.dat}
X Y
3 5
4 6
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data3.dat}
X Y
5 7
6 8
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%  width=\linewidth,
%  xmin=0,xmax=10,
%  ymin=0,ymax=10,
%  axis y line*=left,
%  axis x line*=bottom,
legend style={xshift=-2cm}  % adjustable
legend cell align=center,   % left,center, right, 
  ]

\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=o}
\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=x}
\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=*}

    \addplot[color=black, mark=o, draw=none] table [y=Y, x=X]{data.dat};
    \addlegendentry{\hspace{.3cm}New record};
    \addplot[color=black, mark=x, draw=none] table [y=Y, x=X]{data2.dat};
    \addlegendentry{\hspace{.3cm}Discarded solution};
    \addplot[color=black, mark=*, draw=none] table [y=Y, x=X]{data3.dat};
    \addlegendentry{\hspace{.3cm}Reset to record}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```